# Notepad++: Find & replace with regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi there im having in multiple files the text below and i want to change them with Notepad++. I've searched the internet and many "guyides" but no luck yet.

```
<ingredient id="57" count="10000000"/>
```

and i want to do it like this

```
<ingredient id="57" count="10000000" isTaxIngredient="true" />
```

the count is always integer.

Im searching for this

```
<ingredient id="57" count="\d+"/>
```

and replace all with this

```
<ingredient id="57" count="\1" isTaxIngredient="true" />
```

How my expression should be?

Comment: write a small script to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing missing are parentheses that show which part of the regex match you want to capture in backreference `\1`:

```
<ingredient id="57" count="(\d+)"/>
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

You simply forgot the parenthesis around your \d+

```
<ingredient id="57" count="(\d+)"/>
```

This tells notepad++ the different group that you want it to match (and retreive using the backreferences)

Regards,

Manny